# Trying to create new dataset using macro sas

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have the following code:

```
              %macro One (Data=, City=);
                 data &data; 
                 set Dataset1;
                 Var_new=.;
                 if State = "CA" and CITYCODE = &City then output;  
                 run;
              %mend One;
              %One (Data=Bakersfield_CA,  City=12540);
              %One (Data=Chico_CA         City=17020);
```

I get the first dataset for Bakersfield_CA..but I get error for the second time the macro runs and I don't get any dataset called "CHico_CA".

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a comma in your second macro call. Try

```
%One (Data=Bakersfield_CA,  City=12540);
%One (Data=Chico_CA,         City=17020);
```

In general, though, creating lots of little datasets like this is a bad idea, as it makes your code much more complicated than necessary. What are you trying to do for each city? You can probably do the same thing with your original `dataset1` using by-group processing.

Comment: Thanks..I"ll try that. I am trying to create a separate dataset for each city because I will then be using the different dataset with ODS to output certain information into excel.

Comment: You still probably don't need to bother with a separate dataset per city. You could write ODS code that reads the same dataset each time but with different `where` conditions, for example.

Comment: Can you give me an example?